# What should <Banking Userid> be in discoverAndAddAccount() in Customer Account Data API

Tags: aggregation, intuit-partner-platform, customer-account-data-api

I just played with Customer Account Data API yesterday so I am a completely newbie to this platform.

I have tried to google and search for description of Banking Userid but I didn't succeed. For a real Banking Userid, what is it? Let's say I have a checking account at CIBC. Is the "Banking Userid" the account number? Card number? And the password as well. Is the password required in discorverAndAddAccount() the password of the card? or the password when we do online banking?

Answer (score 3):

If you were to login to their web interface, what do they ask for. This would be what you would enter.